# Data Validation Testing using selenium

Tags: selenium, testng, database

I am doing functional automation testing for a web application for analytics using selenium+TestNG. This application fetches huge amount of data from database and displays it on the platform after some simple calculations.

I am also trying to do data validation testing for this application and want to know the approach I should take. The developers will be able to provide the data in a tsv file(since I do not have access to database) and I would like to validate this data with the data displayed in the application.

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction so I can perform data validation along with functional testing and also keep the framework scalable.

Answer (score 2):

This application fetches **huge** amount of data from database and displays it on the platform after some **simple** calculations.

- Please define **huge**
- Please define **simple**

The developers will be able to provide the data in a tsv file(since I do not have access to database) and I would like to validate **this data** with the data displayed in the application.

- Is **this data** the data developers give you in tsv format?

Your objectives are:

- Data validation testing: you will have to learn from developers about how the data is calculated. With the same algorithm and the same batch of data input, you can compare the displayed data against data calculated by your script.
- Functional testing: I am not sure which functional testing you want to perform as you have not provided us with any specifications / design objectives.
- Scalable framework: I am assuing the major factor for you to worry about scalability is in the future the huge amount of data to be processed by this website will become "huger"; there is a chance your testing scripts need to be scaled up to accommendate this increase in input data size. Apart from generic practices ([external reference 1](https://www.techwell.com/techwell-insights/2014/07/scalability-automated-testing), [external reference 2](http://automation-beyond.com/2009/06/09/qa-test-automation-requirements-scalability/), [external reference 3](https://www.borland.com/es-ES/Blog/November-2015/Building-a-Robust-Test-Automation-Framework?feed=blogs)) that you can adhere to, I am thinking of introducing multiple-threaded test execution. If you can make sure your tests are thread-capable, your tests will stand strong against future increase in input data size.

Comment: Huge means there are approximately 20,000-30,000 records displayed for each combination I select and there are around 70 combinations I can create. Simple calculation refers to operations like min, max average on the data being displayed